# Use ItemSource with ListViewItem in sorting

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have problem with sorting the listView in WPF. This work with binding, but I want to keep manipulation with ListViewItems. My problem is ItemSource is null in default. If I set itemsource like bellow, is not null, but my sort function is not work.

```
ObservableCollection<ListViewItem> allFormats = new ObservableCollection<ListViewItem>();
foreach (Item drd in formats) {
  ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
  // Section with ListViewItem manipulation. Set drd values, set tag etc...
  allFormats.Add(lvi);
}
lvFormats.ItemsSource = (ICollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(allFormats);
```

Sort function:

```
private void Sort(string sortBy, ListSortDirection direction)
        {
            CollectionView dataView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ItemsSource);

            if (dataView != null)
            {
                dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
                SortDescription sd = new SortDescription(sortBy, direction);
                dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
                dataView.Refresh();
            }
        }
```

In binding this work, because I directly have class in Collection view. Here I have `CurrentItem = {System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem: { cFormats = aaaa, cFormatID = 3, cFormatIDVersion = 6 }}`. In xaml I'm not use binding.

Comment: Those "ListViewItem manipulations" should be done in an ItemContainerStyle in XAML. You should not be creating ListViewItems manually.

Comment: @Clemens. Why creating ListViewItems manually is not good?

Comment: Because creating UI elements in code behind is generally not recommended. WPF has the concept of templates, i.e. control templates and data templates. The typical way to pass items to an ItemsControl like a ListView is by binding its ItemsSource property to a collection of data items. Then you define how these items are displayed by either setting the ItemTemplate property, or by declaring DataTemplates that are automatically chosen by their DataType property. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).